# Undefined references in mingw32.a

Tags: c++, mingw

When using mingw-w64 in Fedora, I have a problem compiling this as a dynamic library:

```
#include <windows.h>

extern int main(int argc, char* argv[]);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, INT)
{
    return main(__argc, __argv);
}
```

The linking errors I get are:

```
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):(.text.startup+0x17)||undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_nShowCmd'|
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):(.text.startup+0x28)||undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_lpCmdLine'|
/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib32_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):(.text.startup+0x31)||undefined reference to `__mingw_winmain_hInstance'|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Comment: dll's don't have a `WinMain` only an optional `DllMain`. Add the build command used to your question.

Comment: This is so projects using the library can use the standard main function even in a Win32 project and keep portable code. It's used in other libraries (SFML) and compiles, but not in this case. I'm building it in CodeBlocks so I don't know what the exact build command is. I'm linking libgcc and libstdc++ statically with the project, only enabled compiler flags are -s, -O2, -std=c++0x, linker for dynamic libs is i686-w64-mingw32-g++ for static libs i686-w64-mingw32-ar.

Comment: You can find the commands under *Build log* tab near the bottom.